# How can I pass fake data to my view (testing sort of - I know you don't test Views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a wizard with a bunch of "steps" and in each step a bunch of "inputs" (textboxes, radio button lists, checkbox lists, drop downs).

Everything is working great, but I am now trying to perform some calculations on my final "Submitted" step of the wizard, and I need to do two things:

1) Work out the logic of a+b+(c*2), etc. I don't need to "test" this, I just have a bunch of if/else clauses and am mapping out the calculations.

2) In order to facilitate the above, and to see the output (including the CSS / UI and stuff) rather quickly, I want to pass fake data from all the steps. How best to do this?

I am using a bunch of Models / ViewModels, so `MyModel` might have:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and `MyViewModel` would have:

```
public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }
```

Now, there are about 10 models pulled into one view model, and basically there are like 50+ inputs. My problem is if I want to see the end result of "Submitted" I have to go through the wizard each time.

I'd like to just skip that for this purpose, pass fake data without going through the entire wizard (assume my entry point is my "Confirm" step which has a button to "Submit", so I'd like to start at "Confirm" and then click "Submit" (otherwise, maybe I can just start at "Submitted" step)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't unit testing this so a way you could fake this is to create a dummy view model in the controller's confirm get action:

```
    var MyViewModel dummyModel;

    var infoStepModel info;
    info.property = xxx;

    dummyModel.Property = XXX;
    dummyModel.Property = 123;
    dummyModel.infoStep = info;

    return View(dummyModel);
```

Then change the properties to the settings you need in order to test out each part of your post logic.  It will be a little slow as you will need to change the properties every run until you have tested all the logical flow.

Without a testing framework you are forced to run the program and input each step as you have described.  With this you can at least forego doing each step over and over again and you can go straight to the confirm step and have the fake data ready.

Additionally, if you move the logic out of the controller's post action and into a class that takes in the model you could also more easily test this if you are using a testing framework.  You would then be using the controller to only pass the data in and perhaps respond to the classes result that it passes back.

Comment: Thanks, that works out great just for a quick and dirty implementation. Not too worried so much changing it out so much at the moment, but yes, I should think about a testing framework. I am new to programming, so adding Testing is a bit overwhelming as I wouldn't even know how to go about it. I sense more reading/research on my horizon. :)

Comment: Could you suggest a framework that would help with exactly this and is relatively easy to implement?

Comment: There are several, NUnit and XUnit seem to be pretty popular.  MS Test is also baked right in to VS.